PyTorch loss.backward() Error: TypeError: 'NoneType' object is not callable
I encountered an error while training a Siamese network using PyTorch. When I call loss.backward() after calculating the loss, I receive a type error. Below are the error messages and the relevant code.
Error Message
Traceback (most recent call last):  
  File "/home/xxx/PyProject/image_similarity/Grad_CAM_Siamese/01.Train_Siamese_model.py", line 250, in <module>  
    loss.backward()  
  File "/home/xxx/anaconda3/envs/pytorch_siamese/lib/python3.8/site-packages/torch/_tensor.py", line 487, in backward  
    torch.autograd.backward(  
  File "/home/xxx/anaconda3/envs/pytorch_siamese/lib/python3.8/site-packages/torch/autograd/__init__.py", line 200, in backward  
    Variable._execution_engine.run_backward(  # Calls into the C++ engine to run the backward pass  
TypeError: 'NoneType' object is not callable

Code Snippet
Here's the relevant code snippet near 01.Train_Siamese_model.py line 250 where the error occurs:
for epoch in range(params['hyperparameters']['epochs']):
    torch.cuda.empty_cache()
    model.train()
    loop = tqdm(train_dl, leave=True, ncols=120)
    metrics = {'losses': []}
    for step, (img1, img2, img3) in enumerate(loop):
        img1, img2, img3 = img1.to(device), img2.to(device), img3.to(device)
        optimizer.zero_grad()
        loss = model(img1, img2, img3)

        # I try to get some infomation about the loss value here

        loss.backward()  # Line250
        torch.nn.utils.clip_grad_norm_(parameters=model.parameters(), max_norm=params['hyperparameters']['max_norm'])
        optimizer.step()

Some infomation about the loss value before loss.backward() is as follows:
tensor(1.0018, device='cuda:3', grad_fn=<MeanBackward0>)  # loss
Loss type: <class 'torch.Tensor'>  # type(loss)
torch.float32  # loss.dtype

Here’s the part of the code where I calculate the loss:
self.loss_fnc = TripletLoss(margin=1.0)

loss = self.loss_fnc(embeddings_anchor, embeddings_positive, embeddings_negative)  

class TripletLoss(torch.nn.Module):
    def __init__(self, margin=1.0):
        super(TripletLoss, self).__init__()
        self.margin = margin

    def forward(self, anchor, positive, negative):
        distance_positive = F.pairwise_distance(anchor, positive)
        distance_negative = F.pairwise_distance(anchor, negative)
        losses = torch.mean(F.relu(distance_positive - distance_negative + self.margin))
        return losses

Additional Information

Python Version: 3.8.17
pytorch==2.0.0 torchvision==0.15.0 torchaudio==2.0.0 pytorch-cuda=11.7
CUDA Version: 11.7 (by nvcc -V)
Training Device: GPU

I tried calling loss.backward() after calculating the triplet loss in my Siamese network training script. I expected this operation to compute the gradients for backpropagation without any issues. However, instead of successfully calculating the gradients, I received a TypeError indicating that a 'NoneType' object is not callable. This error prevents me from proceeding with training the model.

Are you sure this code is representative? The TripletLoss code you have provided produces a loss with grad_fn=< MeanBackward0>, while your code shows ToCopyBackward0.

@Karl Thank you for pointing that out! I realized that the output loss value should indeed show grad_fn=<MeanBackward0>. I will correct this in my post.
